# Transferir foco del icono de la aplicación al JTextField de username de inicio de sesión al iniciar aplicación JAVA

Tags: java, focus

Al iniciar mi aplicación Java desde el icono de escritorio, el foco se mantiene en el icono, y necesito que el foco cambie del icono al jTextField del nombre de usuario, que aparece al iniciar la aplicación.

He probado con jTextField.requestFocus, pero el foco sigue manteniendose en el icono de escritorio al iniciar la aplicación.

Comment: ¿Te fijaste en los comentarios de [esta pregunta](/q/234068)?

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega más información, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola David, por lo que dices de que el foco sigue en el ícono, debes tener declarado algo como: **frame.setFocusable( false );**, pasalo a **true** y volverá la alegría.